# $(f(X))=f((X))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $A, B$ be two rings and let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be an epimorphism. 
> Prove that if $f$ is an epimorphism,then for any subset $X \subseteq A,\ f((X))=(f(X))$.

I've been asked to do this exercise, so far I've got this:

Since $(f(X))=\bigcap\{I \trianglelefteq R \mid f(X) \subseteq I\}$ if $f((X))$ is an ideal then $(f(X)) \subseteq f((X)) $ becasue $(f(X))$ is the smallest ideal that contains $f(X)$ 
To prove that $f((X))$ is an ideal we show that $a+b \in f((X))$ and $ya\in f((X))$ 
For $a+b \in f((X))$ we take $a^{\prime}, b^{\prime} \in (X)$ such that $f(a^{\prime})=a$ and $f(b^{\prime})=b$. Then, given that f is a homomorphism
$$a+b=f(a^{\prime})+f(b^{\prime})=f(a^{\prime}+b^{\prime})$$
But, since (X) is an ideal,  $a^{\prime}+b^{\prime}\in (X)$. Therefore $a+b\in f((X))$

Now, for $ya\in f((X))$ we have that since f is surjective $\exists x\in (X)$ such that $f(x)=y$, therefore $$ya=f(x)f(a^{\prime})=f(xa^{\prime}) \in f((X))$$
Again, because $(X)$ is an ideal

Is this okay? Also, I'm stuck trying to prove that $f((X)) \subseteq (f(X))$

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Note that any element in $(X)$ can be written as $$\sum_{j=1}^n a_j x_j$$ for $a_j\in A$ and $x_j\in X$, then the last inclusion is not hard to check.

Comment: I want to mention that your definition of epimorphism is nonstandard. Typically, this is defined categorically to mean if $g_1 \circ f = g_2 \circ f$ then $g_1 = g_2$. Surjections are epimorphisms, but not all epimorphisms are surjections. Take for instance the inclusion $\mathbb Z \longrightarrow \mathbb Q$.

Comment: [duplicate, I guess](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3665401/prove-fx-fx-is-necessary-for-f-to-be-an-epimorphism?rq=1)